# create copy of already made function with new parameters?

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function `freq01()`, when a button is clicked I want a `function(new)` to create a copy of function `freq01()`, with new parameters. I have no idea where to start or if JS can create a function from a function.

All variables have been created. Please point me in the right direction...!

The code below is to save the checked radio button value to an array.

```
function freq01(){
  if (document.getElementById("w01").checked){
   incFreq = document.getElementById("w01").value;
  }
  else if (document.getElementById("f01").checked){
   incFreq = document.getElementById("f01").value;
  }
  else if (document.getElementById("m01").checked){
   incFreq = document.getElementById("m01").value;
  }
}
```

Comment: you have multiple radio buttons. you need to call this function dynamically. is that what you are asking?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I wouldn't recommend creating a new function, but use parameters in the function, and reference them later, rather than hardcoding them. Can you please explain what you would like your second function to do?

Comment: Taking a step back and rethink your design is probably the best way to go. Please describe what you want to achieve.

Comment: It looks a bit unusual that novice in JS needs to generate functions in real time.

Comment: Yes I think I might be in over my head here... :/

Comment: You say you want to "create a copy of `freq01` with new parameters", but your example `freq01` function currently doesn't take any "parameters" (arguments?)? Do you mean you want to have different functions that rely on different HTML DOM element ID's (e.g. not "w01", "f01", and "m01")? More clarity is needed on that part.

Answer (score 0):

> I have no idea ... if JS can create a function from a function.

To answer this part of your question, yes Javascript can create a function from a function. Any function can return another function, and the typical ways to do this would be to create a *factory* function, or use function *currying* to create new functions:

## Factory

A function that returns another function. Due to Javascript closures, you can set "private" variables that the returned function can see, but the calling function cannot access:

```js
function addTwoFactory() {
  let a = 2;
  return function(b) {
    return a + b;
  }
}

let f1 = addTwoFactory();
let f2 = addTwoFactory();
console.log(f1(3)); // 5
console.log(f2(3)); // 5
```

Can also make configurable factories that can create different sorts of methods:

```js
function makeAdder(a) {
  return function(b) {
    return a + b;
  }
}

let addTwo = adderFactory(2);
let addThree = adderFactory(3);
console.log(addTwo(3)); // 5
console.log(addThree(3)); // 6
```

## Currying

Function currying is the idea of taking a base function that takes several parameters, and "baking in" one of the parameters, to reuse more easily:

```js
function adder(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

function makeAdder(a) {
  return function(b) {
    return adder(a, b);
  }
}

let addTwo = makeAdder(2);
console.log(addTwo(3)); // 5
```

Comment: Great! If this answered your question, don't forget to click the green checkmark next to the voting buttons for this answer, to mark it as "accepted"!

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use bind https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

```
    var freq01 = freqBase.bind(null, "w01","f01","m01");
function createNewFunc(i){
  return freqBase.bind(null, "w0"+i,"f0"+i,"m0"+i);
}

function freqBase(a,b,c){
  if (document.getElementById(a).checked){
   incFreq = document.getElementById(a).value;
  }
  else if (document.getElementById(b).checked){
   incFreq = document.getElementById(b).value;
  }
  else if (document.getElementById(c).checked){
   incFreq = document.getElementById(c).value;
  }
}

var func2 = createNewFunc(2);
var func3 = createNewFunc(3);
func2();
func2();
func2();
func3();
func2();
```

Other idea is to just return new function

```
var newf1 = function createNewFunc(i){
  return function(){ return i;}
}

newf1(1)();
newf1(1)();
newf1(1)();
```

shorter version could be:

```
a = (i)=> ()=> { return i; }
```

or more readable

```
const f2=function createNew(i){
   return ()=> { return i; }
};
const res = f2(1)();
```